# std::max_element compile error, C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, std, lookup

Please see the following 2 examples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin>>n;
    std::vector<int> V(n);
    // some initialization here
    int max = *max_element(&V[0], &V[0]+n);
}
```

This gives the following compiling error:

> error C3861: 'max_element': identifier not found

But when I replace the call of `*max_element(&V[0], &V[0]+n);` to  `*max_element(V.begin(), V.end());` it does compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin>>n;
    std::vector<int> V(n);
    // some initialization here
    int max =*max_element(V.begin(), V.end());
}
```

Could somebody explain me why the two are different?

Comment: It's all about [*argument-dependent lookup*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: What if you used `std::max_element` ? In the first case, the arguments are raw pointers so argument dependent lookup doesn't apply. In the second case, those iterators certainly belong to namespace std.

Comment: Second snippet is not guaranty to work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to [argument dependant lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (aka ADL).

Since `max_element` is defined in the namespace `::std`, you should really write `std::max_element` everywhere. But, when you use it in its second form

```
max_element(V.begin(), V.end());
```

since `V.begin()` and `V.begin()` have type defined itself in `::std`, ADL kicks in and *finds* `std::max_element`.

Comment: `Note that std::vector<..>::iterator` is not required to be in `std`.